# torchvision installation problem: avcodec-58.dll not found

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, torchvision

I am having an odd issue with torchvision installation.  I just installed torch/torchvision with the folowing pip command:

pip install torch===1.4.0 torchvision===0.5.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

system:
OS: win 7, python 3.6.8, with cuda

the error: when I do:
import torchvision

I get a pop up "python.exe - System Error" "The program can't start because avcodec-58.dll is missing from your computer..."

I have torch/torchvision running on another win machine (10, cpu only) without problems.

Someone suggested installing ffmpeg, which did not help.  The thing is that my other win PC never had ffmpeg and torchvision installation works fine there.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this?

and what is avcodec-58.dll anyway?

EDIT:
It turns out there are two versions of ffmpeg static and shared.  Apparently chocolatey installs the static one and the shared one is needed by torchvision as it is the one with the dlls including avcodec-58.dll.

Comment: avcodec-58.dll is lib which have a lot of codecs for decoding different videos & audios. like mp4,mov.avi etc. It is provided by ffmpeg.